# Netbeans Hibernate reload on context redeploy

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jpa, netbeans, initialization

I am using Netbeans as IDE and developing webapplication using Primefaces and Hibernate.

When I make a small change in the code, the context reloads and even hibernate reinitializes everything ...

this is very time consuming for a database of about 300 plus tables ...

Is there another way of using hibernate with tomcat?

Comment: JRebel is an excellent (paid for) tool. http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/. I did come across a similar free tool recently but can't remeber what it was called. Doubt it would be as good anyway. Some things are just worth paying for!

Comment: so there is no other way? sessions factory via jndi or something like that ... container supported/managed rather than per project/context